# React: Module parse failed

Tags: reactjs

I finished setting up node v13.14.0 on my windows 7 laptop then did "npm react-create-app name". After done downloading I was greeted with this error...

[Image of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUePY.png)

I tried searching it on stackoverflow there was a solution about webpack.config.js but I couldn't find it on my folder section.

[vscode-folder-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpVW2.png)

Any idea, should reinstall ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by creating a new user in windows (I found the solution on github comments somewhere ), then logged in as that user and installed "npx create-react-app app-name" and it worked somehow ¯_(ツ)_/¯.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD8uw.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing then use `npm i create-react-app`. If you are trying to creating react app then use `npx create-react-app appname`. If you have another issue then please elaborate on that issues.

Comment: sorry I miss typed there